# Mac Terminal - Run Command On Each Line Of Output

Tags: git, command-line, terminal, backup, rsync

I recently started using Git as a version control system and deployment workflow for my company's website files. I have yet to find a simple way to back up just the updated files in a Commit (this way all of the project files don't get redundantly backed up every time), and I've brainstormed a way to output the files in a Commit using the following command:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only {COMMIT_ID}
```

...where `{COMMIT_ID}` is the 8-character ID of the Commit.

This works, and outputs the files in a nice way, one file on each line.

What I wanted to do is capture each line of this output, which may be e.g.:

```
/a/b/c/file1.txt
/a/b/c/d/file2.txt
/x/y/file3.txt
/x/y/z/file4.txt
```

...and perform the following Terminal command on each line of this output to make a copy of each file with `rsync`:

```
rsync -aR ~/Git/repo/./{OUTPUT_LINE} ~/Commit/repo/{COMMIT_ID}/
```

...where `{OUTPUT_LINE}` is this line of the output (e.g. `/a/b/c/file1.txt`) and `{COMMIT_ID}` is the 8-character ID of the Commit from earlier.

## TLDR;

How can I run a command on the result of each line of a multiline output from a Terminal command?

### Further Notes

- I'm familiar with the `|` pipe, but only on a fundamental level, and I'm not sure how to utilize it for this.
- To expand on my `rsync` command: this grabs the diff file from the my local directory that houses the Git repo files, creates the directory structure of the file, and one-time copies the file over. No sync.
- I plan to use this backup workflow in an AppleScript that asks for the Commit ID in a dialog box so you can quickly copy, paste, and go. Then it will run the terminal command, and fire one last prompt on completion.
- The full series of Terminal commands that will perform this backup are as follows:

```
mkdir ~/Commit/repo/{COMMIT_ID}
cd ~/Git/repo
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only {COMMIT_ID}
rsync ...
```

Explanation:

1. Create a new directory in the `~/Commit/repo/` backup folder
2. Load this Git repo
3. Show the files that were changed in the last Commit
4. For each one, `rsync` the files to the backup folder

Answer (score 1):

[`xargs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html) is your friend:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only "$COMMIT_ID" |
xargs -L 1 -I FILENAME rsync -aR ~/Git/repo/./FILENAME ~/Commit/repo/"$COMMIT_ID"/
```

options:

- `-L 1` -- read the input one line at a time, instead of the default which is to fit as many of the input items as possible into the command line.
- `-I FILENAME` -- use the string "FILENAME" as the placeholder for the input item.

Comment: Could you expand on what each of the flags in this `xargs` statement are doing?

Comment: Some comments added. Reference [your `xargs(1)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html)